# Sending data whenever network becomes available

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsoperation

I have an app where I have to send a set of data to the server. I can do that using NSURLSession or other APIs. The problem is that I need to trigger the code for sending the data as and when network becomes available . The triggering of this action should work even if the app is in background/suspended. I am divided between using performFetchWithCompletionHandler or handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession. Currently I am using the former.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        //do some check for loggedInStatus here

        if loggedInStatus {

            let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

            let myViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! MyViewController

            //checking network connection
            if NetworkReachability.connectedToNetwork() {

                myViewController.syncStuff({ (result: UIBackgroundFetchResult) in

                    completionHandler(result)
                })
            }

        }
    }
```

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

//if user is logged in set a minimum time interval at which the app should be woken up to sync stuff
        if loggedInStatus {

            application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(5)
        }
        else {

            application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalNever)
        }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that this method will get triggered only when the app is in background, on some interval, but I cannot send stuff if the app is in foreground with this approach. What is the proper way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Aim at your question: trigger upload when your app is in foreground.

I doubt your solution which send data to sever only when the network become available is good. If the network is always available during your app is in foreground you have no chance to send data. So I think you should change your upload strategy, such as setting a timer and its fire time interval when your app becomes active, invalidate the timer when your app enters background.

And I doubt myself not understanding your question correctly, if you want to send data to server only when the network changed from WWAN to WiFi, you can use AFNetworking's [AFNetworkReachabilityManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h), just copy .h and .m file to your project is ok.